# JQuery To check all checkboxes in td based on classname of tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my sample code

```
<table id="accessListTable">
<tr class="ui-grid groupHead">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="3"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="ui-grid groupHead">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="groupHeadCheck"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="4"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

1. E.g, When the checkbox in first row with class `groupHeadCheck`, all the checkboxex of `id` **1**, **2** and **3** will also be checked.
2. And if all the checkboxes of 1, 2, and 3 are already checked, the checkbox in first row will be checked.

Please any help!

Comment: can you change the html?

Comment: Hi Pete, can't change html structure as some restrictions. Thanks.

Comment: I was more thinking about adding classes to the inputs rather than changing the structure, that way you could group your inputs and make it easier to write js for what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure it can be done in a prettier manner, but this is the basic idea:

```
$("table tbody").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function (e) {
    var currentCB = $(this);
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    if (currentCB.is(".groupHeadCheck")) {
        var allCbs = currentCB.closest('tr').nextUntil('tr.groupHead').find('[type="checkbox"]');
        allCbs.prop('checked', isChecked);
    } else {
        var allCbs = currentCB.closest('tr').prevAll("tr.groupHead:first").nextUntil('tr.groupHead').andSelf().find('[type="checkbox"]');
        var allSlaves = allCbs.not(".groupHeadCheck");
        var master = allCbs.filter(".groupHeadCheck");
        var allChecked = isChecked ? allSlaves.filter(":checked").length === allSlaves.length : false;
        master.prop("checked", allChecked);
    }
});
```

and if you need to run the code to force the check all state

```
$(".groupHead").next().find("[type=checkbox]").change();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udH5C/1/)

Comment: Thanks it works for #1 of question, but I also need #2 solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a click handler to the group checkbox then inside the handler you can find its tr element and the tr's next sibling element till the next occurrence of `tr.groupHead`

```
$(function ($) {
    $(".groupHeadCheck").on("click", function (event) {
        $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr.groupHead').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked)
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nQG7G/)

Comment: Hi Arun, it works if `groupHeadCheck` is checked all checkboxes are checked. But I also need if all checkboxes like 1,2 and 3 have already been checked, the first checkbox `groupHeadCheck` will be checked. Bcuz I have two pages like view and edit.

Answer (score 0):

This would check all if the first is checked (or uncheck all)

```
$(document).on('click', '.groupHeadCheck',function() {
     $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr.groupHead').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'))
});
```

you could fiddle a bit with your classes (or IDs) to make it right for you

Comment: you would need to use prop to check and uncheck a checkbox - for some reason attr has bugs with it when setting the checked status - [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270689/attrchecked-checked-does-not-work)

Comment: never noticed that, but I will take your word for it and keep it in mind :)

Comment: Hi Alex, I updated the question, it works for #1, but need also for  #2. Please!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already answered, but I wanted a more generic way of doing this. In my case, I wanted to check all in a column until I hit a new group. I also had 3 columns with checkboxes. The ones in the first checkbox column all had names starting with "S_", the second "A_" and the third "C_".  I used this to pick out the checkboxes I wanted.  I also didn't name the heading checkboxes that were used to do the "check all" so it would stop when it hit the next groupings row.

You could use the class name to apply the same logic.

First, here is what a check all checkbox looked like:

```
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="checkAll(this, 'S_');" />
   </td>
```

Then the javascript function it calls when clicked:

```
function checkAll(sender, match)
{
    var table = $(sender).closest('table').get(0);
    var selector = "input[type='checkbox'][name^='" + match + "']";

    for (var i = $(sender).closest('tr').index() + 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        var cb = $(table.rows[i]).find(selector).get(0);
        if (cb === undefined)
            break;

        if ($(cb).is(':enabled'))
           cb.checked = sender.checked;

    }
}
```

So it will search each subsequent row for a checkbox with the name starting with "S_". Only the checkboxes the user has rights to will be changed.  I was going to use $(td).index() to find the right column, but this didn't work out because some rows had colspan's greater than 1.